# Removing Bitmoji icon from Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have downloaded Bitmoji long ago, and the Bitmoji icon appeared on Whatsapp. It is extremely annoying because wherever I put it it will always get in my way at some point. I have no idea how to make it go away. Is there a way? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings, try unchecking the option "Show In-App Floater - Display a floating Bitmoji head in popular chat apps to make sharing a breeze"

It didn't work the first time I did this, so I went back in, checked and unchecked again and then it was gone.

Comment: Worked at first attempt.